# Solutions for outer join operator (+) not allowed in operand like OR or IN

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex, outer-join

I have tried the following query but I still get this error and I am not able to find a solution to resolve it. I want to be able to get one of the three dates (LOAD,LAST_MODIFIED,ORDER_ITEM_LAST_UPDATE) according to the situation. However, I need also to use the actual calendar date to use a specific column inside.  It is why I do the join (+) with the LOAD_DATE. Now, I try to find a way not to get the error ORA-01719, Someone can help me?

ORA-01719: outer join operator (+) not allowed in operand of OR or IN
01719. 00000 -  "outer join operator (+) not allowed in operand of OR or IN"
*Cause:    An outer join appears in an or clause.
*Action:   If A and B are predicates, to get the effect of (A(+) or B),
try (select where (A(+) and not B)) union all (select where (B)).
Error at Line: 17 Column: 35

CODE:

```
SELECT A.PRODUCT_ID AS KEY,
       TO_CHAR(A.ORDER_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY') AS ORDER_CREATION_DATE,
       TO_CHAR(B.LOAD_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY') AS LOAD_DATE,
       TO_CHAR(B.LAST_MODIFIED_DATE, 'MM/DD/YYYY') AS LAST_MODIFIED_DATE,
       TO_CHAR(B.ORDER_ITEM_LAST_UPDATED, 'MM/DD/YYYY') AS ORDER_ITEM_LAST_UPDATED, 
       A.ORDER_STATUS AS ORDER_STATUS, 
       A.ORDER_ITEM_STATUS AS ORDER_ITEM_STATUS, 
       A.ORDER_ACTION AS ORDER_ACTION,
       NVL(B.ORDER_ITEM_ACTION, 'NOT APPLICABLE') AS ORDER_ITEM_ACTION,
       NVL(B.CEASE_REASON, 'NOT APPLICABLE') AS ORDER_CEASE_REASON,
       A.PRO_SYSTEM AS PRO_SYSTEM, 
       CASE WHEN (A.PRO_SYSTEM = 'X') THEN 'Y' ELSE 'Z' END AS FLOW 

         FROM PART1 A, PART2 B,DATA_REP_CALENDAR CAL 

       WHERE A.ORDER_SEQ = B.ORDER_SEQ
       AND TRUNC(B.LOAD_DATE) = CAL.ACTUAL_CALENDAR_DATE (+)
         
        AND TRUNC(B.LOAD_DATE) BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS( TO_DATE('07/01/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY'),- 6) and LAST_DAY( TO_DATE('07/01/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY'))        
        OR TRUNC(B.LAST_MODIFIED_DATE) BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS( TO_DATE('07/01/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY'),- 6) and LAST_DAY( TO_DATE('07/01/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY'))
        OR TRUNC(B.ORDER_ITEM_LAST_UPDATED) BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS( TO_DATE('07/01/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY'),- 6) and LAST_DAY( TO_DATE('07/01/2019', 'MM/DD/YYYY'));
```

Comment: Just rewrite it using a standard `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Could you please  show me how to use it in my code ? I am quite new with SQL so I am a bit confused here

Answer (score 0):

A simple example based on Scott's `EMP` and `DEPT` tables; there's department 40, and nobody works in it. If you want to display it (while joining those tables), use outer join. The "old" Oracle outer join operator is `(+)` which has its ... *drawbacks*. If you use `outer join`, many things (that won't work with `(+)`) will now work.

This is what you have now:

```
SQL> select d.deptno, d.dname, e.ename
  2  from dept d,
  3       emp e
  4  where d.deptno = e.deptno (+)
  5  order by d.deptno, e.ename;

    DEPTNO DNAME          ENAME
---------- -------------- ----------
        10 ACCOUNTING     CLARK
        10 ACCOUNTING     KING
        10 ACCOUNTING     MILLER
        20 RESEARCH       ADAMS
        20 RESEARCH       FORD
        20 RESEARCH       JONES
        20 RESEARCH       SCOTT
        20 RESEARCH       SMITH
        30 SALES          ALLEN
        30 SALES          BLAKE
        30 SALES          JAMES
        30 SALES          MARTIN
        30 SALES          TURNER
        30 SALES          WARD
        40 OPERATIONS

15 rows selected.

SQL>
```

This is how you should rewrite it:

```
SQL> select d.deptno, d.dname, e.ename
  2  from dept d left join emp e on e.deptno = d.deptno
  3  order by d.deptno, e.ename;

    DEPTNO DNAME          ENAME
---------- -------------- ----------
        10 ACCOUNTING     CLARK
        10 ACCOUNTING     KING
        10 ACCOUNTING     MILLER
        20 RESEARCH       ADAMS
        20 RESEARCH       FORD
        20 RESEARCH       JONES
        20 RESEARCH       SCOTT
        20 RESEARCH       SMITH
        30 SALES          ALLEN
        30 SALES          BLAKE
        30 SALES          JAMES
        30 SALES          MARTIN
        30 SALES          TURNER
        30 SALES          WARD
        40 OPERATIONS

15 rows selected.

SQL>
```